# why is sign flag not set with cmp -75, 55 in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements, flags, cmp

I have in my textbook a table (from intro to assembly by dandamudi, pg 249) where it says that when you execute this code:

```
cmp -75, 55
```

that the sign flag is not set but the overflow is. this makes no sense to me as through the chapter and everywhere I have researched it says that the sign flag is set if the result of an operation can be interpreted as negative, and there is no reference to any other situation.  I know the cmp instruction tests by subtraction without changing the destination, so why is only the overflow flag set in this case?  This table was to show that the conditions for `Snum1 < Snum2` are that `SF != OF`.

Comment: Both are immediates, so I wonder how the assembler assembled the instruction at all. Otherwise, take a look at [that](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html) reference.

Comment: Dandamudi shows it in the 8-bit range ("cmp AL,DL" on p. 246). CMP subtracts the second operand from the first operand: -75 - +55 = -130. (-130) doesn't exist in the 8-bit range - it becomes (+126). The result is positive (no sign) and overflowed.

Comment: Very nice guide to understanding carry and overflow conditions / flags: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Comment: Added that link to the x86 tag wiki, up in the "learning resources" section, since this is nowhere near the first time I've linked it on an SO question.

Comment: your right if the number goes out of range of the register negativly and the overflow is set it will be interpreted as a positive number, so num1<num2 whenever the SF != OF thanks for making that clear.